# Highlight a certain author in references

Tags: xml, jekyll, citations, csl

I'm trying to create a list of references using `jekyll` and `jekyll-scholar`.
Is there a way to highlight (boldface) the name of a certain author in the CSL style file? Is there a better way to achieve the same effect without touching the CSL style file?

For example (from [here](https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/13052/csl-10--bold-name-initials-of-1st-author-in-bibliography-/)), this would be desirable:

**Zelle R.M.**, E. de Hulster, W. Kloezen, J.T. Pronk, and A.J.A. van Maris. 2010. Key process conditions for production of C4-dicarboxylic acids in bioreactor batch cultures of an engineered Saccharomyces cerevisiae strain. Appl. Environ. Microbiol. 76:744-750.

Abbott D.A., **Zelle R.M.**, J.T. Pronk, and A.J.A. van Maris. 2009. Metabolic engineering of Saccharomyces cerevisiae for production of carboxylic acids: current status and challenges. FEMS Yeast Res. 9:1123-1136.

**Zelle R.M.**, E. de Hulster, W.A. van Winden, P. de Waard, C. Dijkema, A.A. Winkler, J.A. Geertman, J.P. van Dijken, J.T. Pronk, and A.J.A. van Maris. 2008. Malic acid production by Saccharomyces cerevisiae: engineering of pyruvate carboxylation, oxaloacetate reduction, and malate export. Appl. Environ. Microbiol. 74:2766-2777.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bibliographic entries can be post-processed with a [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/) template (see jekyll-scholar's [README](https://github.com/inukshuk/jekyll-scholar/blob/master/README.md) for background). To highlight my name in the example, you can use the following in _config.yml:

```
gems:
  - 'jekyll/scholar'
scholar:
  bibliography_template: "{{ reference | replace_first: 'Zelle, R. M.', '<b>Zelle, R. M.</b>' }}"
```

For a full example, see https://gist.github.com/inukshuk/51e4a2b527eb605845fa.

Comment: (courtesy of the author of jekyll-scholar, Sylvester Keil, who helped me answer this question)